# Access permission in adb as root : can't access database

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, adb, root

So I made a basic android application that inserts data in SQLite Database using Async, and I would like to view this database and the tables it contains.
The android monitor doesn't allow me to oppen the data file, so I tried to use the command line using :

```
C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb root
```

Then I get this message :`adb unable to connect for root : protocol fault (couldn't read status): connection reset by peer`
And I tried also without connecting as root using just :

```
adb -s <device code> shell
shell@m0:/ $ /data/data/com.example.user.myapplication/databases/mydb.db
```

But it gives me this message :

```
can't execute : permission denied
```

I tried to run this command :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
```

when it opened the shell I used the Super User command :

```
shell@m0 :/ $ su
```

And it successfully connected as root:

```
root@m0:/ #
```

In spite of that I still get the permission denied message when I want to access the database. I'm out of options.

I should point out the fact that my android device is rooted.

Comment: the database file is not an executable thus `can't execute : permission denied`

Comment: Well then how am I supposed to access the database ?

Answer (score 0):

you can:

1) get the DB with the command: adb pull /data/data/com.example.user.myapplication/databases/mydb.db

2) launch <android sdk path>\platform-tools\sqlite3 mydb.db  and use SQL commands within (eg. SELECT * FROM table1)

Comment: You can't pull the database without changing the permission with chmod command. But thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

I just found out how to overcome the permission denied problem and get access to database.
Actually the problem with what I've been doing is that I was trying to get access to file that had a permission of only execution and not read and/or write. You can see the type of permission either by Android Device Monitor or by typing this command in the adb shell :`ls -l`
So what you need to do is to change the permission type from execute only to read/write/execute, which is done by this command : `chmod 777 /data`
Actually you need to chmod 777 every directory from /data until /data/data//databases/dbname.db so that you can access the db and pull it into a directory in your computer.
See the full documentation in this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825304/Accessing-internal-data-on-Android-device
I hope this helps you.
Don't forget that I was connected to the adb shell as root (by rooting my android device and executing the adb shell in Super User mode).